# How to change DocumentRoot to local directory in XAMPP VM?

Tags: macos, xampp, virtual-machine, document-root

I have used XAMPP on Windows. There I could easily change the DocumentRoot in `httpd.conf` to a local folder, like `C:\mysite`.

However, I can't get it to work with XAMPP VM for macos. I tried to edit the `httpd.conf` when `/opt/lampp` is mounted and restart the server but it did not work.

Answer (score -1):

make sure your config looks like this

```
 DocumentRoot "C:\mysite"
        <Directory "C:\mysite">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Comment: I tried to set the document root that way but it did not work. Are you sure this also how it works on macos xampp vm since your directory example is from windows?

Comment: Not working on my environment, getting a 403 Access Denied Error